# Discordjs v13 EMBED_FIELD_VALUE

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Every time I use this command, I get the error "if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
^
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.". This error is very frustrating as it prevents the bot from functioning properly. I would appreciate if you could help me modify my code so that I no longer have this error. Your assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  name: 'movieinfo',
  description: 'Affiche des informations sur un film, une série, un anime ou un épisode.',
  category: ' Films et séries',
  usage: '<titre du film, de la série, de l\'anime ou de l\'épisode>',

  async execute(message, args) {
    try {
      const apiKey = 'API KEY';
      const query = args.join(' ');
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?api_key=${apiKey}&language=fr-FR&query=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      const results = data.results;

      if (!results || results.length === 0) {
        message.channel.send(`Désolé, je n'ai pas trouvé d'informations pour "${query}".`);
        return;
      }

      const mediaTypes = results.map(result => result.media_type);
      const uniqueMediaTypes = [...new Set(mediaTypes)];
      const mediaType = await askMediaType(message, uniqueMediaTypes, query);

      const filteredResults = results.filter(result => result.media_type === mediaType);
      const result = filteredResults[0];

      if (!result) {
        message.channel.send(`Désolé, je n'ai pas trouvé de ${mediaType.toLowerCase()} pour "${query}".`);
        return;
      }

      let title, releaseDate, overview, posterUrl, startDate, endDate, year, rating, voteCount, contentScore, numberOfSeasons, numberOfEpisodes;

      if (mediaType === 'movie') {
        title = result.title;
        releaseDate = result.release_date;
        overview = result.overview;
        posterUrl = result.poster_path;
        year = releaseDate ? new Date(releaseDate).getFullYear() : null;
        rating = result.vote_average;
        voteCount = result.vote_count;
        contentScore = result.popularity;
      } else if (mediaType === 'tv' || mediaType === 'anime') {
        title = result.name;
        releaseDate = result.first_air_date;
        overview = result.overview;
        posterUrl = result.poster_path;
        startDate = result.first_air_date;
        endDate = result.last_air_date;
        year = startDate ? new Date(startDate).getFullYear() : null;
        rating = result.vote_average;
        voteCount = result.vote_count;
        contentScore = result.popularity;
        numberOfSeasons = result.number_of_seasons;
        numberOfEpisodes = result.number_of_episodes;
      } else if (mediaType === 'person') {
        title = result.name;
        releaseDate = null;
        overview = result.biography;
        posterUrl = result.profile_path;
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`Désolé, je ne suis pas en mesure de fournir des informations pour "${query}".`);
        return;
      }

      const releaseYear = releaseDate ? ` (${new Date(releaseDate).getFullYear()})` : '';
      const posterEmbed = posterUrl ? new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${posterUrl}`) : null;

      const infoEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${title}${releaseYear}`)
        .setColor('#f8ecfc');

      if (mediaType === 'movie' || mediaType === 'tv' || mediaType === 'anime') {
        if (year) {
          infoEmbed.addField('Année', year, true);
        }

        if (rating) {
          infoEmbed.addField('Note des utilisateurs', `${rating}/10`, true);
        }

        if (contentScore) {
          infoEmbed.addField('Score de contenu', `${contentScore.toFixed(1)}/100`, true);
        }

        if (mediaType === 'tv' || mediaType === 'anime') {
          if (numberOfSeasons) {
            infoEmbed.addField('Nombre de saisons', numberOfSeasons, true);
          }

          if (numberOfEpisodes) {
            infoEmbed.addField('Nombre d\'épisodes', numberOfEpisodes, true);
          }

          if (startDate) {
            const endDateString = endDate ? ` - ${new Date(endDate).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR')}` : '';
            infoEmbed.addField('Dates de diffusion', `${new Date(startDate).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR')}${endDateString}`, true);
          }

          if (overview) {
            infoEmbed.addField('Synopsis', overview);
          }
        }
      }

      message.channel.send(`Je vous ai trouvé plusieurs ${mediaType.toLowerCase()} correspondant à "${query}" :\n${filteredResults.map(result => result.title || result.name).join(', ')}`).then(() => {
        const embeds = [infoEmbed, posterEmbed].filter(embed => embed && embed.fields.length > 0 && embed.fields.every(field => field.value.trim() !== ''));
        message.channel.send({ embeds });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      message.channel.send('Une erreur vient de se produire.');
    }
  },
};

async function askMediaType(message, mediaTypes, query) {
  const mediaTypeString = mediaTypes.map((mediaType, index) => `${index + 1}. ${mediaType.toLowerCase()}`).join('\n');

  const mediaTypeMessage = await message.channel.send(`J'ai trouvé plusieurs types de médias pour "${query}". Veuillez choisir un type de média en tapant le numéro correspondant :\n${mediaTypeString}`);

  const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && /^\d+$/.test(m.content);

  const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });

  const choice = parseInt(collected.first().content);

  if (choice < 1 || choice > mediaTypes.length) {
    message.channel.send(`Désolé, "${choice}" n'est pas un choix valide.`);
    return askMediaType(message, mediaTypes, query);
  }

  return mediaTypes[choice - 1];
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone will check your whole snippet above for an error they don't know more about. You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76182484/edit), add the full error message and only post relevant code, not your whole file.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not the full error stack. Anyway, what is the type of `year`, `numberOfSeasons`, `numberOfEpisodes`? Are they integers?